# Biodegradation time for biodegradable shopping bags?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, plastics, environmental-chemistry

How long does it take for the plastic/polythene shopping bags marked **biodegradable** to *biodegrade*?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the environment and on the definition of *degrade*.

In an anoxic landfill, a *very* long time before any change is noticed. Even in a wet environment, open to air and sunlight, only *the cornstarch additive* decomposes.

Initially, it was thought that adding cornstarch would help speed decomposition (and provide an outlet for surplus farm products), but [studies such as this](http://www.ajer.org/papers/v2(7)/C0272227.pdf) show that though some speed in decomposition is gained (shown by water absorption), tensile strength of the plastic is decreased by adding starch, so yet *more* plastic is needed to make the material sufficiently strong (and the bags still rip).

Also, though the corn-starch additive can decompose rapidly, [this study](http://naldc.nal.usda.gov/download/24481/PDF) shows that the polyethylene, though now fragmented, does not further decompose. This leads to [run-off of microparticles into lakes and oceans](http://oceans.mit.edu/featured-stories/269000-tons-plastic-ocean-now-dr-marcus-eriksen).

So if your definition of *biodegrade* means how long does it take for the bag to shred, [according to yet another study](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01458290#page-1) performed in a heated environment with added oxygen, about a year. At the end of that time, though, perhaps 80% of the initial mass remains, mostly polyethylene fragments. Much of this eventually is washed into oceans, [is eaten](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/from-fish-to-humans-a-microplastic-invasion-may-be-taking-a-toll/), and winds up in us, as well.